# Reference Request: Equivariant Symplectic bordism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cobordism, equivariant-homotopy

Non-equivariantly, symplectic bordism has  been  developed  extensively  by  Ray, Gorbunov, and  specially  S. Kochman in this memoir: http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/memo/0496 Yet  the  coefficients  remain  unknown  outside  of  the  range reached  by  Kochman.

Is  there  any development  of  equivariant symplectic  bordism?

Comment: You could try emailing Nige Ray (http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nige/) (who was my advisor).  I'm not sure if he has formally retired, if so it will be quite recent, but he is still active.